# Background/content bottom half disappears when resizing/maximizing window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

So my website http://developed-web.com/ is starting to come together pretty good but I'm having this issue with everything that's not on-screen having to disappear when I take the window out of maximized mode.

This issue occurs in Google Chrome, Firefox and IE 10 too.

I'm not used to this kind of site structure so I don't wanna mess stuff up even more while trying to fix this. What could the issue be?

Thanks for taking a look :)

**EDIT:**

Go to the page in maximized window, and when you take it out of maximized (not minimize, just make it smaller) som content will disappear: http://gyazo.com/a5744085b32b1cf05acc4e1efa653da9

Comment: after resizing scroll to bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely familiarise yourself with the debugging tools in your browser. My preference is developer tools in Chrome (`CMD+alt+i` on a Mac, `F12` on Windows). There's a great guide from Google [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/videos) to get you started.

If you look at the console tab you'll see that your JavaScript is throwing an error in the `resizePanel` method when you resize the window on the home page.

If you look at the elements panel and resize the window you will see that something is setting the height of your mask element to the size of the window.

To fix both errors, try updating your code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.panel').click(function () {

        $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        current = $(this);

        $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);      

        return false;
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizePanel();
    });

});

function resizePanel() {

    width = $(window).width();
    height = $(window).height();

    mask_width = width * $('.item').length;

    $('#debug').html(width  + ' ' + height + ' ' + mask_width);

        // These lines are erroneously setting the height of the mask to the
        // height of the window so when the user scrolls down, an area of
        // unmasked content is visible. 
        //$('#wrapper, .item').css({width: width, height: height});
        //$('#mask').css({width: mask_width, height: height});

        // Try updating as follow as kpsuperplane has suggested
        $('#wrapper, .item').css({width: width});
        $('#mask').css({width: mask_width});

        // This was throwing an error because no anchor elements have
        // the selected class when the page is first hit
        if ($('a.selected').length) {    
            $('#wrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);
        }   
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to put this `$('#wrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);` ?

Comment: I don't know if it's what causing the visual bug you're seeing, but it's certainly worth addressing. Your first parameter to scrollTo is undefined and it's causing the plug-in to throw an error. Have a look in the console when you resize and you'll see it.

Comment: So which one of these solutions would you suggest?

Comment: kpsuperplane's suggestion should fix the bug you've asked about. My fix will stop the JavaScript error.

Comment: This is solving the mentioned issue but gave a new one instead. If you go to the site and take it out of maximized you'll see that it instantly changes to the "contact" page.

Comment: the issue with resize instantly switching to "contact" page disappeared when removing `$('a.panel').eq(0).addClass('selected');`

Comment: But now you've got the JavaScript error back ;). See my updated answer which now checks for the existence of an anchor tag with the selected property before calling the scrollTo plug-in. Stick that in and I think you should be sorted.

Comment: There we go, changed to the latest. How's the js error now? Thanks, by the way :)

Comment: You're looking good there Dave - all free of errors! Good luck with the rest of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere javascript is adding a fixed height to your #wrapper when the window is resized, ill try and find out why this is happening to you.

---- i think this error is causing your problem

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined on line `jquery.scrollTo.js:11`

Its not just when you resize the window either it happens to me if i switch tabs

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('#wrapper, .item').css({width: width, height: height});
$('#mask').css({width: mask_width, height: height});
```

to

```
$('#wrapper, .item').css({width: width});
$('#mask').css({width: mask_width});
```

in your `resizePanel()` js function (it can be found in the script tag in the head if you look at source)